# Two SIM cards having same IMSI

Tags: android, mobile, gsm, imei

Is there any possibility of having same IMSI(International Mobile Subscriber Identity) number in two different SIM(Subscriber Identity Module) Cards globally.

I'm asking this because there is possibility of existing same mobile number in different countries across the world.

Comment: @Shruti you can't just say its not possible, need to prove or explain why, that's more valuable. Otherwise i would answer your comment saying "Why not?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMSI  contains country code MCC and Network code MNC

Theoritically it is unique across the world.

But can be copied or spoofed.

It cannot be duplicated in different countries.